# A question about functions uniformly approximated

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let *X*, *Y* be compact metric spaces. If *f*, *g* are continuous real-valued functions on *X* and *Y* respectively, we denote by *f*⊗*g* the function such that (*f* ⊗*g*)(*x*,*y*) = *f*(*x*)*g*(*y*) Show that every continuous function on *X* × *Y* can be uniformly approximated by $\sum_{i=0}^n fi⊗gi$ where *fi* is continuous on *X* and *gi* is continuous on *Y*

I am sorry, because first time to upload a question, I can't type the formula well. I will upload a picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F68tt.png)

Comment: I first prove that the new function is continuous, and I want to show that the new funcional space constructed by the new function is compact . But I don't know how to prove the new function can be approximated uniformly by the finite function series

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of Stone -Wierstrass Theorem. There is no simpler proof.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy.  I know I should prove the functional space generated by the new definition function is dense, but how should I prove it can uniformly approximated by finite series

Comment: The functions of the form $f \otimes g$ separate points and then the finite sums form their generated algebra, which must then be dense. Please state what version(s) of S-W you have learnt.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So in this problem,you mean I shouldn't care the finite series,because n can get arbitrary natural number?

Comment: All sums are automatically in the algebra generated by all $f \otimes g$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you very much. I think too much about the problem, all the sums can generated, I can always choose the sum to approximate the function. I get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One version of the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) says:

> Let $X$ be compact Hausdorff, and consider the algebra $C(X)$ of real-valued coontinuous functions on $X$ (in the topology induced by the uniform metric). Then a subalgebra $\mathcal{A}$ that contains a non-zero constant function, is dense in $C(X)$ iff $\mathcal{A}$ separates points.

Then it suffices to note that the set $\mathcal{P}:=\{f \otimes g: f \in C(X), g \in C(Y)\}$ of $C(X \times Y)$ separates points of $X \times Y$ (as $C(X)$ separates points of $X$ etc.) and contains all constant functions on it. As $\mathcal{P}$ is also closed under pointwise multiplication (and also scalar multiplication) we see that the algebra it generates is just $\{\sum_i h_i: h_i \in \mathcal{P}\}$ and by the Stone-Weierstrass theorem it is dense (we can approximate all real-valued continuous functions on $X \times Y$ by these sums).